# How to avoid duplicate entries in nested iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator, amazon-s3

How can I rewrite this to avoid duplicate entries?

```
images.each do |img|
  thumbs.each do |th|
    html << link_to(image_tag("#{th.url}"), "#{img.url}")
  end
end
```

I want to wrap thumbnail images `th.url` into links to original images `img.url`

**up:**
I'm using a [fog](http://fog.io/0.11.0/storage/) gem to get `images` and `thumbs` from S3.
They're files with different prefixes:
`storage.directories.get(bucket, :prefix => "thumbs").files`

Comment: You should provide more details here. What is `images` and what is `thumbs`. I think `images` is an array of Paperclip objects. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not relate your images and thumbnails in some way?

So if your image is called `image_name.jpg` you could have your thumbnail called `thumbs/image_name.jpg`.

If your names are unconnected, then why not just associate them in your application so you use an associative array of images and thumbnail names?

```
my_images = [ "image_1.jpg"=>"aflafffff_thumb.jpg", "image_2.jpg"->"zofofroro_thumb.jpg" ]
```

Either of those ways enable you to just find the corresponding thumbnail for each image.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through two collections (images and thumbs) - hence the duplicates. Guessing your image and thumb objects are linked somehow...

e.g. thumbs available doing something like image.thumb

```
images.each do |image|
  html << link_to(image_tag(image.thumb.url), image.url)
end
```

By only iterating through the images collection you won't get duplicates.

Comment: the problem is that they're not linked. They are files in S3 with different prefixes and I'm using fog gem to retrieve them.